# Numbers Won't Open On My MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.5

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm not a tech or computer expert - I understand clear directions, but not tech-speak, so I'm going to put this as plainly as I can…

I've updated to the most recent system, OS X 10.8.5, on my MacBook Pro. My Pages and Keynote applications are opening and functioning fine. However, when I attempt to open and utilize my Numbers application, it either either does nothing, or flashes a message that the document can't open.

I have tried to search other answer sites for insight into what might be going on, without finding a direct answer. Would you please explain to me why this might be happening, and how I can troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: When I click on the Numbers icon on my dashboard, or from my launchpad, literally nothing happens. When I click on an actual document from my files, this message pops up: "The application 'Numbers' can't be opened. -1712". Thanks.

Comment: Does rebooting fix it? Does it work in safe mode (⇧-boot)?

Comment: No, I've tried shutting it down and back on, as well as restarting it. I haven't tried it in safe mode, as I've had negative experiences with that in the past.

Comment: What about uninstalling and re-installing it, might that help?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions - I'm always learning something new. I just read up on uninstalling such apps, and of course, it's more complicated than I thought, since sometimes parts of apps get left behind and screw with future installations? Have you ever heard of this service before? - http://macpaw.com/landings/land166?campaign=search_text_cmm_uninstall_us&utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_campaign=&gclid=CPLPipCP4LoCFSgSMwod8UsA5Q&siteID=&CJPID=&mpaid=

Comment: Indeed, *fully* uninstalling an app requires that you delete all associated preferences. However, since the app won't open at all, all that might be needed is to delete the Numbers.app from /Applications, then re-download it from the Mac App Store. Whilst I do have CleanMyMac 2, for thoroughly uninstalling apps I recommend the free [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) but in this case it's probably unnecessary. Try simply deleting Numbers.app and downloading it again.

Comment: Alright, I'm baffled. I tried to trash the App, but it told me I couldn't because it was open. So, I forced quit it. Then I trashed it. Then I re-downloaded it...Nada. I click on a Numbers doc and the doc icon just blinks a little, but no doc appears. Sigh.

Comment: Hallelujah! The process I described above must have worked, I just had to wait until it took. I just went into my files and they ALL opened, both my Numbers files and the associated Excel docs! Thanks for all your guidance, grgarside. Never signed up to become an armchair tech expert, but I guess it goes with the territory now. ;)

Comment: I have the exact problem. Numbers and Pages do not open under Mountain Lion 10.8.5. It does not matter whether you click on the application or on a file created in the application. Changing user does not help. Funny, I had mistakenly bought a KeyNote last summer. It opens and works well. By the way, Pages and Numbers were working under earlier versions of Mountain Lion

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do when troubleshooting an iWork app that connects to iCloud is to test launching the app from a brand new user. This will isolate whether your user settings are causing problems or the problem is truly with the App itself or the OS install.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select Users & Groups
3. Make a new user - test or something obvious.
4. Log out of your current user (users if you have fast user switching enabled).
5. Log in to the new account.
6. Open Numbers.

At that point, you can see if the console app has information about Numbers from the current user launching the app and the previous user. Console app is in /Applications/Utilities.

Since this won't actually solve the problem you may need to edit the question or ask a new question - but it should help inform you if the problem relates to your documents in Numbers or the Numbers app itself. From there, you'll have a more narrow problem to ask/chase/fix.